# I am trying to implement paytm subscription

Tags: node.js, paytm

I am putting the values of mandatory parameter in step-2. but it gives error that Something went wrong. The transaction request sent by you is incorrect. Kindly email your `MID - XXxVMh74422683748269`, Order ID - TEST_1593759129069 and order time - Jul 3, 2020 12:22

Here is the link for subscription-payments in paytm
https://developer.paytm.com/docs/v1/subscription-payments/

Answer (score 0):

Paytm Subscription is enterprise solution and it require to be enable on the paytm backend system on the merchant ID (MID).
Looks like the subscription is not configured for your merchant id( mid) at Paytm side. Please raise the request to developer support. Kindly check after subscription gets configured on your mid in staging environment.

Comment: Now its configured but renewal Api giving error

Response:  {"head":{"responseTimestamp":"1594213525390","version":"v1"},"body":{"resultInfo":{"resultStatus":"F","resultCode":"501","resultMsg":"System Error"}}}